# Visual Studio plug-in that mimics eclipse environment

Tags: visual-studio, eclipse

I have been using eclipse development environment for almost 3 years. Now I am about to move to C# and Visual Studio IDE.

Does anyone know a Free/Open Source plug-in for Visual Studio to that mimics eclipse environment?

Comment: I have to tell you that after using both, I prefer VS because it seems less "busy" or cluttered. I think that you may find the same after a bit of using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ReSharper (jetbrains) is a nice plugin enhancing the VisualStudio. However it is not free/open source. Nevertheless it is really worth its price!

Comment: While I adore Resharper, I would also be glad for any information on how to change key bindings of VS to match Eclipse (e.g. hitting ctr +/ for comments etc...)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with lewap.  Resharper is really almost a must have if you are coding in C# on Visual Studio.  Resharper adds a lot of built in refactorings and shortcuts that you don't get with Visual Studio.  While it isn't free it's not too bad of a price ($349 commercial, $199 personal) for something that will save you a lot of time in the long run.